# How to successfully host a public-facing website on an organisation's own internal network?

Tags: networking, internet-connection, webserver, website

An organisation I'm involved with wants to host a publicly-facing website on their own internal network rather than using a professional hosting service.

I need to help them make sure they can host their website on their internal network and still have it accessible to the public at decent performance and reliability.

Initially I focused on QoS protocols/traffic congestion, which I now think isn't relevant. The organisation's concern is their own internal network causing bottlenecks. Now I want to focus on LAN connection technologies used for the web server.

What LAN connection technologies should be used when hosting a publicly-facing website on a web server that's connected to an organisation's internal LAN?

Comment: So you have a customer whose network is causing lag for accessing their own website?

Comment: Are you saying this organization wants to host a public-facing website on their own internal network (rather than using a hosting service), and you want to make sure public access to the website is fast and reliable even though it's not being professionally hosted in a well-connected data center?

Please edit your question to better explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: The organisation wants to ensure their internal LAN doesn't cause bottlenecks i.e. their internally hosted website is supported at a decent data rate. @Spiff you've explained exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: But you've just contradicted Spiff's comment by only mentioning that you're only interested in internal LAN clients. If your website is hosted internally then, pretty much all the time, the website should be pretty damn quick. But this depends on whether your clients are connected by Gigabit, that your web server is up to the job for both internal and external clients, your website coding/framework/platform is suitable for the expected traffic, you've configured it correctly for things like caching, minification, you've optimised images, and that you've thought of things like QoS.

Comment: "explain how they (the organisation) can support their web site at a decent data rate (they have a high speed connection to the Internet and do not want their internal network to be a bottle neck). This is about the network connections, NOT Quality of Service issues." 

you should identify appropriate LAN technology that can address the problem and explain how each technology provides a solution to their problem.

Comment: The organization's WAN link (broadband Internet connection) is far more likely to be the limiting factor than your LAN technology. It would also be helpful to know if there are any load estimates or scalability goals. How many connections per second do you get now, or do you want to plan for getting in the foreseeable future? What's your average page weight (total bytes of a typical page plus all images and css/js files and other resources loaded as part of that page)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to have to do a lot of assumptions, but here we go:

Likely your customer's internet connection is less than 1000Mbit/s. If the webserver is connected with Gigabit Ethernet to the internal network, no congestion will occur on the LAN (as the congestion will occur on the internet connection first).

Assuming the webserver has enough CPU/memory/IOPS available and is only used for hosting the website, you should be able to fill the entire internet connection without saturating the internal network. That is, if the router is able to support that many seperate HTTP client's requests.

If their internet connection is more than 1000Mbit/s, you could upgrade to 10G Ethernet (switches and network cards are readily available from all major server vendors). Probably the webserver won't be able to fill a 10G connection anyways, depending on the code you run on the server.

To specifically answer your question regarding LAN technologies: IEEE 802.3.

For a more practical side of things: hosting a website on your internal website can be tricky business (security-wise). If they really want to host in on their internal network (for whatever reason), they would do well to hire a professional who knows about this stuff. A decent firewall, DMZ solution, IDS and/or WAF would definitely be advisable.

Comment: I'd add that the technologies referred to in the last paragraph of this answer are definitely a hard requirement if you don't want the internal network compromised from a security standpoint.

Comment: I wrote my Answer below from the assumption that the organization is tiny and has no budget, but I endorse @mtak's answer here if the organization has some money to spend to do this as well as can be done by a non-hosting-savvy organization that is really stuck on the idea of self-hosting for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is the advice I'd have for even the smallest businesses or nonprofits that have a small office LAN with some kind of small business broadband and want to have some kind of self-hosted, but publicly-accessible, website:

1. Use gigabit Ethernet on your office LAN. Make sure you have a wired gigabit (or better) Ethernet path all the way between your broadband modem and your web server. Make sure all routers or firewalls or switches on that path not only have gigabit Ethernet ports, but also have the CPU speed to do their job at full gigabit line rate.
2. Your small office router/gateway probably uses NAT (really NAPT). Make sure it's a professional grade device and supports NAT loopback (a.k.a. NAT hairpinning), otherwise accessing your own website from your own office will be a pain in the ass.
3. Make sure your office broadband service has at least 100Mbps of *upstream* bandwidth. Spend money on business-class Internet service that comes with a "Service Level Agreement" (SLA) that specifies bandwidth, (low) latency, (low) packet loss rate, and uptime guarantees.
4. It IS very much relevant to watch out for congestion, especially on the broadband upstream direction. Before messing around with QoS, first make sure your router does some kind of smart queuing such as FQ-CoDel so that congestion can't cause lag (latency spikes). Here's a good article by a Speedtest.net (Ookla) engineer on [how to use an FQ-CoDel-aware router to maximize your broadband performance.](https://medium.com/speedtest-by-ookla/engineer-maximizes-internet-speed-story-c3ec0e86f37a)
5. Even with all this taken into account, realize that hosting your website behind your office broadband service is still probably going to be significantly slower and less reliable than what even the cheapest professional hosting services provide.